# Moment Estimate for Simple Linear SDE

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

In a paper I am reading, it is claimed that the SDE
$$
dX_t = b X_t dt + (\sigma X_t + \beta_t) dB_t  , \quad t \in [0,T],$$
satisfies
$$
E\left[ \sup_{t \in [0,T]} |X_t|^p \right] < \infty, \forall p \in [2,\infty), 
$$
where $b, \sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants and $\beta$ is a process satisfying
$$
E \left[  \int_0^T | \beta_t |^2 dt \right] < \infty .
$$
 Is this true?

Comment: What is the definition of $X_t$ ?

Comment: Without additional assumptions on $\beta$ this is not true. Consider for instance $b=0$, $\sigma=0$ and $\beta_t := Z$ for some random variable $Z \in L^2(\mathbb{P})$ which is independent of $(B_t)_t$ and which fails to have a finite moment of order $p>2$ (i.e. $\mathbb{E}(|Z|^p)=\infty$)

Comment: that's what I thought, thank you.